# Setting colspan with Javascript on certain td (without any id)

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to apply some CSS/JS on an existing web page. Within it there is

```
<tr foodtablesupper>
  <td class="subheader" colspan="3">
    Upper Floor
  </td>
</tr>
<tr foodchoice>
  <td class="dish-1">
    Coleslaw
  </td>
  <td class="dish-2">
    Porridge
  </td>
</tr>
<tr foodtablesupper>
  <td class="subheader" colspan="3">
    Mezzanine Floor
  </td>
</tr>
```

I need to change the colspan to 4. How can I address the td and how do I change the colspan attribute just using vanilla-JS?

Comment: If you change a `colspan` you need to make sure that the total of the other rows have as many columns as the row that's been changed. Include the complete table and the JS you tried and failed with a a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your decision actually what selector to use to address your colspanned TD based on the its page context. It should unique enough. I've chosen it to be in your TR with `foodtablesupper` attribute.
There's not enough surrounding markup in your example.
**UPDATE**
Edited the code to address possible several TDs as the author asked.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {

  document.querySelectorAll('tr[foodtablesupper] > td.subheader').forEach(td => td.setAttribute('colspan', 4));

});
```

```css
td{
  min-width:50px;
  background:#aaa;
  text-align:center;
}
table{
  border-spacing: 3px;
}
td.subheader{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr foodtablesupper>
  <td class="subheader" colspan="3">
    Upper Floor
  </td>
</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<button>Make 4 colspan</button>
```

Comment: Great! The `document.querySelector('tr[foodtablesupper] > td.subheader').setAttribute('colspan', 4);` works fine for me. However it effects only the first occurrence of it (I've edited my code sample).
And sorry for the unchallenging question (saw the down vote) - I just gave up when I only found tuts operating with an id.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That's exactly what I was looking for. Lesson learned. :-)